# Angularjs - ng-repeat within an array of objects

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to loop into another array inside an array of objects, my code looks like below, i need to loop in ng-repeat.

panel.name is what i need to loop into

```
(function(){
    data.items = [];
    var panel = {};
    panel.name = ['Student','Faculty','Security,'Staff'];
    panel.label = ['Student','Faculty','Security,'Staff'];

    data.items.push(panel);
}
```

```
<div class="table-panel" ng-repeat="panel in c.data.items">
</div>
```

i would like to loop into the array of panel.name inside ng-repeat, `ng-repeat="panel.c.data.items.panel"` doesn't seems like working

Comment: `...items` is an array, you'd need to use `ng-repeat="item in c.data.items"` and then use `item.name` etc. inside the loop. Or `ng-repeat="item in c.data.items[n].name"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to show names.

```
<div class="table-panel" ng-repeat="panel in data.items[0].name">
  {{panel}}
</div>
```

Since your items is an array you will have to use items[0] to access the panel object that you have pushed in your function.

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kAq8RdQrSooLlm3OxbBX?p=preview)**

Comment: not sure why but, in my code alert(c.data.items[0].name) is still giving the string - 'Student','Faculty','Security,'Staff'

Comment: @Developer You are missing a ' on the right of your security string, maybe that is causing you the problem.

Comment: that was a type error, do you see any error in this- <div class="panel list" ng-if = "show_panel == panel" ng-repeat="panel in c.data.items[0].name"  ?

Comment: @Developer  I'm glad I could help.